# How to find IP address in WinDbg Windows Kernel Debugging

Tags: windows-10, kernel, debug, windbg

I found [this article](https://community.osr.com/discussion/214844), from OSR forums, however, it didn't work in Windows 10.

```
2: kd> x srvnet!SrvAdminIpAddressList
81fb06b8 srvnet!SrvAdminIpAddressList = <no type information>
2: kd> du poi(poi(srvnet!SrvAdminIpAddressList))
85c52090 "127.0.0.1"
```

There is an [undocumented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-process) bit in `!process` to get the environment variables + hostname, but sometimes DNS is failing so need an IP address for log.

```
$$ !process will dump all the environment variables and hostname 0x31 is magic value.
bu module!class::function "!process 0 0x31 wininit.exe; gc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-ndiskd-netadapter

```
$$ find IP address of host
!ndiskd.netadapter -ip
```

Example output:

> 14: kd> !ndiskd.netadapter -ip
> Driver             NetAdapter          Name
> ffffce85591b7450   ffffce8558ff51a0    Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
>
> IP ADDRESSES
>
> ```
> unicast            ffffce855af44040 - 10.6.185.61
> multicast          ffffce855968c040 - 224.0.0.1
> multicast          ffffce855b45e040 - 224.0.0.251
> multicast          ffffce855b449040 - 224.0.0.252
> multicast          ffffce855968c130 - 239.255.255.250
> broadcast          ffffce8559688040 - 255.255.255.255
> broadcast          ffffce855af42040 - 10.6.185.255
> unicast            ffffce8559694040 - fe80::e929:f1ef:83da:31b
> multicast          ffffce855969a040 - ff01::1
> multicast          ffffce855969a130 - ff02::1
> multicast          ffffce855969a220 - ff02::1:ffda:31b
> multicast          ffffce855b423040 - ff02::fb
> multicast          ffffce855b450040 - ff02::1:3
> multicast          ffffce8558c1f040 - ff02::c
> ```

Please note, you need the **private** symbols of `tcpip.sys` for this to work, otherwise:

> 11: kd> !ndiskd.netadapter -ip
> ...
> *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ndis.sys -
> ...
> ***    Type referenced: ndis!_LIST_ENTRY                              ***

---

Another method, if you are using DHCP for your host, then the IP address given to KDNET virtual adapter will be the same, as DHCP server uses MAC address to allocate IP addresses and KDNIC adapter has same MAC as the real NIC. This is printed when the machine first boots and negotiates connection to WinDbg.

```
Connected to target 172.xxx.yyy.zzz on port 50009 on local IP 172.xxx.yyy.zzz
```